# Counting North-East Lattice Paths

Tags: combinatorics

I have been assigned the following homework problem:

> Let $f(m,n)$ be the number of north-east lattice paths which exist from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$.
>
> (i) Show that $f(m,n) = f(m-1,n) + f(m,n-1)$.
>
> (ii) Show by induction that $f(m,n) = \binom{n+m}{n}$.

I've been reading around (the concept of north-east lattice paths is entirely new to me), but still cannot seem to wrap my head around an approach to this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: At each step, you either go north or you go east. If you're at $(m,n)$ with $m,n$ both being positive, how many ways are there to get there, if your last step was north? How many ways if your last step was east? What do you do with these numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $m,n >0$, we have the picture below. The only ways to
get to $(m,n)$ are to start at $(m-1,n)$ and go east
or start at $(m,n-1)$ and go north.

Since the last segment of the path is distinct, for $m,n>0$ we have
$f(m,n) = f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)$.

[image]

If $m=0$ and $n>0$, we see that there is only one path
and $f(0,n) = n$.
Similarly, $f(m,0) = m$.

Using induction, we see that once we specify the south west boundary values, that
all the other values are uniquely defined.

It is easy to check that $f(0,n) = \binom{n}{n}$ and $f(m,0) = \binom{m}{m}$,
and since $\binom{n+m}{n} = \binom{n+m-1}{n} + \binom{n+m-1}{n-1} $,
we see that $g(m,n) = \binom{n+m}{n}$ satisfies the difference
equation and the boundary conditions, hence $f=g$.